# Characterization of weakly open sets

Tags: functional-analysis

Today in my lecture on Functional analysis we studied weakly topology. The professor defined it to be the coarsest topology which makes all the linear functionals in the dual space of X to be continuous. In other words its the final topology $\sigma(X,X^*)$ on $X^*$.

**Then the prof claimed that a set $U$ is said to be weakly open if $\forall x \in U $  $\exists \psi_1,\psi_2 \dots,\psi_n \in X^* , n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0$

$$U_x:=\{y \in X \text{  s.th }|\psi_j(x)-\psi_j(y)|< \epsilon  \text{ for } j=1 \dots n \} \subseteq U$$

Now for some reason I cannot show why this definition makes sense and I cannot prove this from the definition of the weak topology above.
Any someone explain me why this is true. I would be grateful.
Thank you

Comment: Do you know about bases and subbases of topologies? By the way, I think the characterization has to be $\forall x \in U \quad \exists \psi_1,...\psi_n \in X^*, n \in \mathbb{N}, \varepsilon > 0$ such that $U_x \subseteq U$.

Comment: @Zardo I know that the base of the topology consists of sets whose unions form all the sets in the topology. I do not know the definition of sub-base but i can check it. I am going to fix the problem. Could you please explain me why this characterization follows from the definition of the weak topology

Answer (score 4):

The sets $U_{\psi, \varepsilon}(x) = \{y \in X \vert \, \vert \psi(x)-\psi(y) \vert < \varepsilon \}$ for $\psi \in X^*$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ form a subbasis of the weak topology. That means that the set of all finite intersections (which - ignoring the different espilons - can be expressed as the $U_x$ above) form a basis of the weak topology. You can easily see that the sets $U_{\psi, \varepsilon}(x)$ are weakly open as the inverse image of open sets under elements of $X^*$. Therefore finite intersections must be open and unions of those. But the collection of all these sets already form a topology, so this is the coarsest topology in which all elements of $X^*$ must be open, i. e. the weak topology. So every weakly open set can be expressed as the union of sets similar to the $U_x$ of yours and each element must be contained in such a set which is itself contained in the weakly open set.

Comment: SOrry but what do you mean by finite cuts?

Comment: finite intersections! I'm sorry, I'm no native speaker!

Comment: Thanks, I am slowly reading your argument to see if I follow it.

Comment: But why does the set $U_{\psi,\varepsilon}$(x) form a sub-basis of the weak topology?

Comment: This is what I try to explain in lines 3 to 6.